# Complete procedure to implement APNS in ios application

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to implement the push notification in my application .
For this i searched and i found that when my application is not running in foreground then user can be notified by using APNS . And i read many related articles and blogs for this however i got confused because it is not clearly mentioned how to create the server and where it will physically exist .Also APNS (assuming that it is the service provided by apple )will reside with ios on device.

IF some has link which will clearly shows each and every step involved to implement the APNS then please do tell me ..

Thnx in advnce

Paggggyyy123

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12

This will get you the basics..

http://www.raywenderlich.com/3525/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-2

the above will get you with the server part..

If you have any problem..do tell ..